# Can't write Java preferences in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10

I'm trying to run a program that looks for `Java` preferences in `Windows 10` using `JDK 10.0.2`. If it finds them under the system node, it tries to copy them to the user's own node and then the user can change them to their liking. I'm not having any luck in either reading or writing preferences. I've tried a few different JDKs at version 8 and then installed 10 on the theory that it might work better but it didn't.

My program is an old game that I wrote several years ago. It worked fine the last time I ran it in 2012. (At that point, I was probably running `JDK 6` and `Windows XP`.)

I found some code that uses preferences, which is a good bit simpler than my own, in another StackOverflow discussion, modified it a bit, and tried to run it to see if I could come up with an easily reproducible example:

```
    import java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException;
    import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

    public class Prefs01 {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws BackingStoreException {

    Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot(); 

    Preferences preferences = systemRoot.node("fuzz"); 

    systemRoot.put( "foo", "bar" );

    systemRoot.put( "baz", "lolz" );
    System.out.println( "-------------------------------" );

    String[] keys = preferences.keys();
    for( String key : keys ) {
        System.out.println( key );
    }

    System.out.println( "-------------------------------" );

    keys = systemRoot.keys();
    for( String key : keys ) {
        System.out.println( key );
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
```

Debugger shows that systemRoot is "/" after this statement; no error so far.

```
Preferences preferences = systemRoot.node("fuzz");
```

Console produces this message:

```
Oct 01, 2018 5:05:24 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not create windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\fuzz at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.  

systemRoot.put( "foo", "bar" );
```

Console produces this message and stacktrace:

> Oct 01, 2018 5:09:38 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences openKey
>   WARNING: Could not open windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
>   at root 0x80000002. Windows RegOpenKey(...) returned error code 5.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Could not open
>   windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002:
>   Access denied     at
>   java.prefs/java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.openKey(WindowsPreferences.java:553)
>     at
>   java.prefs/java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.openKey(WindowsPreferences.java:515)
>     at
>   java.prefs/java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.openKey(WindowsPreferences.java:501)
>     at
>   java.prefs/java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.putSpi(WindowsPreferences.java:652)
>     at
>   java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.put(AbstractPreferences.java:263)
>     at Prefs01.main(Prefs01.java:13)

Based on the error messages I'm getting, I am under the impression that I have some kind of a Windows authorization issue: I'm not authorized to do what I'm trying to do in the Windows Registry. This makes no sense to me because there is only one `UAC` on this machine and it is an administrator; I don't know of any way to run this program under a different `UAC` even if there were another `UAC` on the machine.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong here and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: You have to make sure you run the java program "as administrator". Try opening a Command Prompt "as administrator" and run you java code from there. Better yet, don't mess with system preferences unless you absolute has to. Just use user preferences.

Comment: How could I possibly be anything but an administrator if I have only one User Account on the computer and it is an administrator?

Comment: This isn’t really how the Preferences class is meant to be used.  I recommend reading the class documentation.  Particularly relevant: “Ordinary applications should have no need to invoke any of these methods, which can be identified by the fact that they are declared to throw `BackingStoreException`.”  If you want to provide internal defaults, keep them as an [importable XML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#importPreferences(java.io.InputStream)) resource in your application.

Comment: @Andreas: For what it's worth, I set the path to the JDK and tried to execute the program from the command line (after compiling it with javac) and got the same errors and stacktrace.

Comment: @Henry Did you open the command prompt by right-clicking and selecting "Run as administrator". Doesn't matter if you're *logged in* as an administrator user, you still have to say "Run as administrator". See articles about **Windows UAC**, e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)

Comment: @VGR: I'm confused. I've been away from Java for several years but back when I was learning how to use Preferences, not too long after they came out, I was confident that I was using them exactly as intended. Has that changed in the intervening years? If so, can you point me to anything that explains how preferences are supposed to be done *now*? I didn't see anything about importable XML in the API when I looked but that might have been a JDK 7 API....

Comment: @Henry This is not a Java issue, but a Windows security issue. Windows has tightened security a lot since Windows XP, and you're running into the extended security blocks added by Windows UAC.

Comment: @Andreas: I tried "run as administrator" and this time the program worked. I read the Wikipedia article you suggested but didn't entirely follow it; there's a lot of unfamiliar stuff in it. What are typical Java users doing - especially in Eclipse - to make their programs work under the strictures imposed by Windows? That would be really helpful to know.

Comment: You're currently using system preferences; does switching to user preferences help at all?

Comment: @Slaw I changed all occurrences of "system" to "user" in the code and ran it in Eclipse and it all executed fine without error messages. Is this nature's way of telling me to simply not use the system node at all and just put all preferences under the user node? Is that what other Java users do? I have to believe other Java developers have a simple approach that works fine and has worked fine since Vista when WIndows started messing with the security for the registry....

Comment: I don't have enough experience to state how the Java community at large uses the Preferences API. All I can say is I've had issues using system preferences in the past and switching to user preferences helped me. Most of the time user preferences made more sense in the context of my application anyway.

Comment: Since the Preferences API was introduced, normal usage of the Preferences class has always been limited to the get and put methods (and userNodeForPackage, import/export, and a few other things).  The documentation covers it fairly well;  if a method throws BackingStoreException, it‘s meant for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the commenters have stated, running "As Administrator" will probably solve the problem.

However, the root cause of your issue is given in this error, and in your code:

```
Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot(); 
...
WARNING: Could not open windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002
```

In the current JDK implementations, `systemRoot` is equivalent to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (as is `0x80000002`).  By default, users don't have write access here without going through UAC.

To resolve this, you'd be best to change your code to use `Preferences.userRoot()`, which accesses registry nodes under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, which is normally writable.